# 165Hz laptop display rendering at 40Hz

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have an Aftershock Vapor 15X (Eluktronics Max 15) with i7-10870H and RTX3060. Even I though I set the refresh rate = 165Hz in the settings, it still renders at 40Hz. Ive tried using multiple DEs like gnome, xfce and kde and the same thing happens each time. Xrandr says its rendering at 1440p 165Hz as well.

- I've tried multiple linux distros, ubuntu, manjaro and debian, same problem. I also installed FreeBSD and installed KDE, same issue - perhaps something wrong with bios or DE?
- I've tried uninstalling intel graphics drivers but it did nothing.
- I've tried setting nvidia prime offset 1, no effect.
- I set the bios to only use dGPU, which worked, but had problems loading the display manager on boot. The screen flickers for a while before loading in.

I think it has something to do with nvidia optimus or some compatibility issues due to newer hardware. Or perhaps something with the intel drivers. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you checking the actual refresh rate? (i.e. how do you know it's 40 Hz)

Comment: The UFO test says its 40fps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about i915 driver. It reads EDID file wrong. Here is the solution:

[i915 driver stuck at 40hz on 165hz screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680356/i915-driver-stuck-at-40hz-on-165hz-screen)